# создание симлинков awk скриптом

Tags: linux, awk

Задача: в моем кросс-sdk отладочные версии либ лежат в каталоге ./usr/lib/.debug
Нужно сгенерить симлинки в диру ./usr/lib/ с именами <имя_либы>d.so

**скрипт awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{  
    len = index($1, ".so") - 1
    start_pos = index($1, "/") 

    name = substr($1, start_pos + 1, len - start_pos)
    dbg_libs[name]=name"d.so"
    rls_libs[name]=$1
}
END { 
    for (name in dbg_libs) {
        command = "ln -s ./"rls_libs[name]" "dbg_libs[name]
        print command, system(commad)
    }

}
```

запускаю из диры ./usr/lib

```
find .debug/ -name "libPoco*"| awk -f ~/make_debug_lib.awk
```

Линки не создаются, но если выполнить вручную сгенерированые команды все ок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

опечатка:

```
system(commad)
```

должно быть:

```
system(command)
```

Comment: Вот это глаз!!!

Comment: как у орла глаз))